# How to calculate rounded up months and days until a target date ignoring timezones and DST?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to create a timer that displays rounded up months and days left before a local target date, ignoring timezones and daylight savings.

To clarify, with a target date `2018-12-10`:

At `2018-10-08 23:01` it should result in `2 months 2 days`
At `2018-10-09 00:01` it should result in `2 months 1 days`
At `2018-10-09 02:01` it should result in `2 months 1 days`
At `2018-12-09 23:59` it should result in `0 months 1 days`

As apparent, days should always start and end at `00:00` local time, independent if the target date is after a DST change in the local timezone or not.

With the naive approach, the DST change throws it off, and it's also not counting less-than-full days:

```
const target = moment('2018-12-10')

const t1 = moment('2018-10-08 23:01')
const t2 = moment('2018-10-09 00:01')
const t3 = moment('2018-10-09 02:01')
const t4 = moment('2018-12-09 23:59')

const d1 = moment.duration(target.diff(t1))
const d2 = moment.duration(target.diff(t2))
const d3 = moment.duration(target.diff(t3))
const d4 = moment.duration(target.diff(t4))

// render() ...
{d1.months()} months {d1.days()} days
{d2.months()} months {d2.days()} days
{d3.months()} months {d3.days()} days
{d4.months()} months {d4.days()} days
```

results in:

```
2 months 1 days
2 months 1 days
2 months 0 days
0 months 0 days
```

What would be the correct approach to calculate the days without being influenced by DST changes during the duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [startOf()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to round the date down first.

So if you do something like this:

```
const target = moment('2018-12-10')

const t1 = moment('2018-10-08 23:01').startOf('day');
const t2 = moment('2018-10-09 00:01').startOf('day');
const t3 = moment('2018-12-09 23:59').startOf('day');

const d1 = moment.duration(target.diff(t1))
const d2 = moment.duration(target.diff(t2))
const d3 = moment.duration(target.diff(t3))

console.log(d1.months() + " months " + d1.days() + " days");
console.log(d2.months() + " months " + d2.days() + " days");
console.log(d3.months() + " months " + d3.days() + " days");
```

The result will be:

```
2 months 2 days
2 months 1 days
0 months 1 days
```

You can also use [isDST()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) to calculate if DST is observed. If it is, you would subtract an hour first. Usage might look something like this:

```
let t1 = moment('2018-10-08 00:01');
t1 = t1.isDST() ? t1.subtract(1, 'hours').startOf('day') : t1.startOf('day');
```